# The show action of Symfony 2 Sonata Admin Bundle is not working

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.6

I'm integrating [Sonata Admin Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/index.html) into my Symfony 2.6 application by following [Symfony 2 jobeet tutorial](http://jobeet.symfony.gr.jp/en/day-12-sonata-admin-bundle.html). Everything is fine except [the Show action](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/action_show.html). I have an entiry "Job" and so I have `src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Admin/JobAdmin.php` which have a function `configurShowField(ShowMapper $showMapper)` like below

```
<?php
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job;

class JobAdmin extends Admin
{
    // ....

    protected function configureShowField(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('category')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('company')
            ->add('webPath', 'string', array('template' => 'IbwJobeetBundle:JobAdmin:list_image.html.twig'))
            ->add('url')
            ->add('position')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('how_to_apply')
            ->add('is_public')
            ->add('is_activated')
            ->add('token')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('expires_at')
        ;
    }

    // ....
}
```

When I click the Show button and go to the view page (admin/ibw/jobeet/job/xxx/show), it shows none of the fields. The original template processed is `/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig`:

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block actions %}
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:edit_button.html.twig' %}</li>
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:history_button.html.twig' %}</li>
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:list_button.html.twig' %}</li>
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:create_button.html.twig' %}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block tab_menu %}{{ knp_menu_render(admin.sidemenu(action), {'currentClass' : 'active', 'template': admin_pool.getTemplate('tab_menu_template')}, 'twig') }}{% endblock %}

{% block show %}
    <div class="sonata-ba-view">
        ***
        {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.show.top', { 'admin': admin, 'object': object }) }}

        {% for name, view_group in admin.showgroups %}
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                {% if name %}
                    <thead>
                        {% block show_title %}
                            <tr class="sonata-ba-view-title">
                                <th colspan="2">
                                    {{ admin.trans(name) }}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </thead>
                {% endif %}

                <tbody>
                    {% for field_name in view_group.fields %}
                        {% block show_field %}
                            <tr class="sonata-ba-view-container">
                                {% if elements[field_name] is defined %}
                                    {{ elements[field_name]|render_view_element(object) }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endblock %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endfor %}

        {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.show.bottom', { 'admin': admin, 'object': object }) }}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The inner content of `<div class="sonata-ba-view"></div>` is not shown except three asterisks I printed. Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a s in your function's name.

it's

```
configureShowFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
```

not

```
configureShowField(FormMapper $formMapper)
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The jobeet tutorial seems incorrect.

Comment: man you save my life, that stupid little s ruined all my afternoon

Comment: however doc still say Fields
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_show.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add call in your admin.yml

```
ibw_jobbeet.admin.jobadmin:
    class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Admin\JobAdmin
    ...
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, ['show', path_to_your_view.html.twig]]
```

[Read more about templates in SonataAdmin](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/templates.html)

Comment: We don't need `setTemplate` explicitly to declare. `\app\Rescources\SonataAdminBundle\views\CRUD\show.html.twig` could automatically overwrites the original template `/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig`. But the problem could not be the template. It could be no result of the variable `admin.showgroups` in the template.